# Fast writes to MongoDB node, but slow to replSet

Tags: mongodb, database-performance, database-replication

I have replSet with 3 nodes (node2, node4 and node6). Node2 has higher priority so it is PRIMARY.

I connect to the primary node from local machine (far away from all the nodes and their local network):

```
mongo --host node2
```

And I insert big document 1000 times:

```
var start = new Date()
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { 
  db.test.insert(<big_document>) 
}
var end = new Date()
print("inserts took " + (end - start) + " milliseconds")
```

Then I do the same, but this time connecting to the replSet, not only single node:

```
mongo --host node2,node4,node6
```

And this time I'm inserting only 10 documents, because I don't have a whole day.

In case of connecting to single node, 1000 docs took 17 seconds.
In case of connecting to whole replSet, 10 docs took 35 seconds.

Why such a difference? When I write to primary node, isn't it also propagating the data to secondary nodes? (even when I explicitely connected only to the primary one)

Mongo 2.4.3

UPDATE:

It turned out there was monitoring turned on on the nodes, which was using much of the bandwidth. Everything is fine when it is turned off.

Still don't know why writing to the PRIMARY node was so much faster than writing to replSet

Answer (score 1):

You likely have the default [Write Concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/) of the replica-set set to *Replica-Acknowledged*. This means that each write operation will block until the other members of the replica-set have acknowledged it. When you don't need this, you can lower the replica-sets default write concern using [getLastErrorDefaults](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#local.system.replset.settings.getLastErrorDefaults) (which is actually a setter method).

Comment: I tried that. I set it to {w:0, j:false, fsync:false}, still it was very slow.